# Salvar imagem no banco de dados POSTGRES com DELPHI Tokyo pelo App Android

Tags: android, delphi, postgresql

Estou precisando salvar uma foto que é tirada na câmera do tablet e salvar a mesma no banco de dados. O tipo do campo o 'typea'. Estou usando o componente Timage para visualizar e referenciar a imagem, mas não consigo salvar ela no banco de dados.

Grato.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `pg_read_binary_file()` para ler arquivos binários armazenados no `data_directory` do servidor postgres.

Considere a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_imagem
(
    id BIGINT,
    nome TEXT,
    imagem bytea
);
```

As imagens podem ser lidas a partir do disco do servidor e imediatamente inseridas no banco de dados em um campo do tipo `bytea`:

```
INSERT INTO tb_imagem ( id, nome, imagem ) VALUES ( 1, 'foobar', pg_read_binary_file( '/var/lib/pgsql/data/imagem1.jpg' ) );
INSERT INTO tb_imagem ( id, nome, imagem ) VALUES ( 2, 'xpto', pg_read_binary_file( '/var/lib/pgsql/data/imagem2.jpg' ) );
INSERT INTO tb_imagem ( id, nome, imagem ) VALUES ( 3, 'kwy', pg_read_binary_file( '/var/lib/pgsql/data/imagem3.jpg' ) );
```

Depois, você pode recuperar a imagem em representação `base64` por meio da funçao `encode()` :

```
SELECT encode( imagem,'base64') FROM tb_imagem WHERE id = 1;
```